# Sequelize order by count association?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have `User` and `Post` table. 
`User has Many Posts` relationship. I want to query User and order the query by the number of posts that the users made. How do I write this sequelize query?

```
Post.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
User.hasMany(Post, {foreignKey: 'userId'});

User.findAll( {
  order: 'COUNT(Post) DESC', //???
  include: [Post]
});
```

How do I get this User query sorted by Post?

Answer (score 55):

There is probably a better way, but you can use a [`.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral) to create a subquery and assign an alias. Then, you can reference the alias when ordering, sample:

```
User.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'User.username',
        [sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE Posts.userId = User.id)'), 'PostCount']
    ],
    order: [[sequelize.literal('PostCount'), 'DESC']]
});
```

This would produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`username`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE Posts.userId = User.id) AS `PostCount` 
FROM 
    `Users` AS `User` 
ORDER BY 
    PostCount DESC
```

Comment: <snide-remark>I love it.  A demonstration of how the intermediate language is (slightly) more verbose than the end result.</snide-remark>

Comment: Thanks for this. Has anyone tried to do this when setting the defaultScope? It works fine when the model is being queried directly, but when I do a multilevel include, it cannot find the column as sequelize now doesn't use the raw table name e.g. 'Post', but instead uses 'User->Post'. So COUNT(*) FROM Post now fails as the table no longer is names the same

Comment: I just want to add that this worked for me, however I had to change the use of sequelize.literal from `sequelize.literal('PostCount')` to `sequelize.literal('"PostCount"')` as without the double-quotes in the query it kept throwing the error that the column did not exist.

Answer (score -1):

sequelize has this, but you need to create an alias for the count

```js
User.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
       [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Post.id')), 'count']
    ]
  },
  include: [{
    attributes: [],
    model:Post,
    duplicating: false,
    required: false
  }],
  group: ['User.id'],
  order: [['count', 'DESC']]
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Turn it around so that sequelize gives you

```
SELECT  u.username,
        COUNT(*) AS PostCount
    FROM Users AS u
    JOIN Posts AS p  ON p.userId = u.userId
    GROUP BY u.userId, u.username
    ORDER BY PostCount DESC
```

That is, start with Post, not User.

Comment: Can you clarify on `turn it around`, how should the JS code look like?

Comment: Sorry, There are dozens of interfaces that generate SQL; I don't keep up with them all.  Many fail to expose SQL well enough to let you get the optimizations you need.

Answer (score -2):

May be this can work

```
var User = objAllTables.User.User();
var Post = objAllTables.Post.Post();

User.hasMany(Post, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
Post.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'});


         User.hasMany(Post, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
            Post.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId'});

            User.findAndCountAll({
                attributes: ['User.username'],
                include: [{ model: Post }]
            }).then(function (result) {
                 console.log(result.count);
                 console.log(result.rows);
            })
```

Comment: This will not order it by count.